# retrieving the url from a link field in a view

Tags: mvc, links

I'm trying to retrieve just the url attribute of a link field for an item in a view.  The view is just using the item as it's model so just retrieving the link field value, which is producing the following:

```
 <link linktype="external" url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanin" />
```

Is there any way other than writing a bunch of parsing code to extract the "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthocyanin" from that?

Comment: So you need `((LinkField)item.Fields["Link Field Name"]).GetFriendlyUrl()`? or I didn't understand the problem?

Comment: What does your view code look like today? Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a helper method on `LinkField` class called `GetFriendlyUrl()`.

Just cast your field to `LinkField` and execute the method like:

```
((LinkField)item.Fields["Link Field Name"]).GetFriendlyUrl()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I was able to use the GetFriendlyUrl() to store the url as a variable that I then inserted into the view markup in the appropriate place.